# How to select the Key of a Record in a Select statement

Tags: apache-kafka, ksqldb

I created this record:

```
new ProducerRecord(topic = "petstore-msg-topic", key = msg.username, value = s"${msg.route},${msg.time}")
```

I want now to do something like this:

```
CREATE STREAM petstorePages (KEY, route VARCHAR, time VARCHAR) \
                  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='petstore-msg-topic', VALUE_FORMAT='DELIMITED');
```

Is there a possibility to access the key in the Stream creation or do I have to include the key also in the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's added automatically and called ROWKEY

> KSQL adds the implicit columns ROWTIME and ROWKEY to every stream and table, which represent the corresponding Kafka message timestamp and message key

https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/syntax-reference.html#id16

Comment: BTW, if you use the Schema Registry with Avro data, then you wouldn't need to specify the Stream schema